# How to get EF Code First DbContext Transaction row identity?

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, ef-code-first, transactionscope

Is it possible to get the identity of a record after the SaveChanges method but prior to the TransactionScope.Complete call using the DbContext?  Do we need to cast to ObjectContext to get this functionality?

We need this when we send a message to a transactional queue on a separate server using MSDTC.

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string qName = ".\\Private$\\DbContextTransactions";
    var db = new BlogDb();

    // force db creation & create queue
    Console.WriteLine("Count={0}", db.Posts.Count());
    if (!MessageQueue.Exists(qName))
        MessageQueue.Create(qName, true); // transactional

    try
    {
        using (var t = new TransactionScope())
        using (MessageQueue q = new MessageQueue(qName))
        {
            var post = new Post() { Title = "Test " + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() };
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // TODO: how do we get post.Id (updated identity)?

            q.Send(post.Id, MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
            t.Complete();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Count={0}", db.Posts.Count());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Once you call `SaveChanges` your post.Id should be filled with correct identity from the database.

Comment: We found "enlist=false" in our connection string that was causing problems with our transactions not enlisting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity value should always be set after you call `SaveChanges`, even inside a `TransactionScope`.

Comment: That isn't what we are seeing in 4.2 and 4.3